# My navigation bar working in microsoft edge,but not good in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I creating a navigation bar to my website, and when I tried the navigation bar in Chrome, its not worked well.
In Microsoft Edge, the navbar is working perfectly.
But in Chrome when I open the navbar and move the mouse to navbar the blur animation starting immediately, its very buggy.

In the Edge, the navbar is working well when I open the animation start only if I move the cursor to the texts.

I have totally no idea what I did wrong. Some expert can check this?

On the site Codepen .io you can see the bugs, and the difference clearly
When you open the navbar, just move the mouse cursor 
between two texts.

Here is the code:

```js
$('.toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('.menu').toggleClass('active');
});

$(window).on("load", function() {
  $('.menu').toggleClass('active');

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  left: 70px;
  top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  background: #0e0f0f;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  z-index: 999;
}

.menu.active {
  width: 85%;
  transition: width 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: width .3s;
  -moz-transition: width 0.3s;
}

.menu.active .menuContent * {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu.active span i:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}

.menu.active span i:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(-100px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu.active span i:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}

.menu span {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #0e0f0f;
  opacity: 0.3;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu span i {
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  width: 45%;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.1s ease 0.1s;
}

.menu span i:nth-child(1) {
  top: 40%;
}

.menu span i:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
}

.menu span i:nth-child(3) {
  top: 60%;
}

.menu .menuContent {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu .menuContent * {
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu .menuContent ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 140px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  color: #2d3235;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.menu .menuContent ul li:hover:before {
  opacity: 0.8;
  top: 13px;
  left: 20px;
}

.menu .menuContent ul li:hover:after {
  opacity: 0.8;
  bottom: 13px;
  left: -20px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #112b38;
}

ul {
  display: inline;
  margin-bottom: 500px;
}

ul li {
  margin: 12px 100px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

ul:hover li a {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity: .2;
  filter: blur(5px);
}

ul li a:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0);
}

ul li a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background: #43bc0b;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  z-index: -1;
}

ul li a:hover:before {
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: #112b38;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>PC Szerviz Sinko</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class='menu'>
    <span class='toggle'>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
  </span>
    <div class='menuContent'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Legujabb.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="szolgaltatasok.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="rolunk.html">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="elerhetoseg.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want to fix the blur bug between two text in Chrome browser.

Comment: Why do you include jQuery *twice*?

Comment: My bad, i don't watch the code enough when i copied.
By the way i'm relativly new in web developing. Sorry.

Comment: I don't see any differences between Chrome and Edge. What versions are you using (and what operating system). Can you be more specific which behavior is the desired result, and what do you mean by "very buggy"

Comment: Its very weird.
I'm using Google Chrome Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)
And using Windows 10 Pro OP System,
I think this is the newest chrome

Comment: You need to move the mouse cursor in navbar exactly horizontal between two texts.
Then you will notify the blur effects start,but in Edge this is not happens.
This happens in my Chrome browser

Comment: In your css you used filter:blur.. and that's causing the blur affect. If you don't want the blur affect just delete the "filter:blur(5px);" in your css

Comment: Yes, i know, but i want the blur effect :)

Comment: I tried it on chrome but I didn't see any bugs. What are you experiencing exactly ?

Comment: I will create a picture about it,and will post a link here.

Comment: Here is the picture:https://imgur.com/a/C5VEQuS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand correctly, you only want the blur when the mouse cursor is on the menu item and not the rest of the navbar.
Try replacing

```
   ul:hover li a
    {

    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: .2;
    filter:blur(5px);
    }
```

with

```
   ul:before li a        
        {

        transform: scale(1.5);
        opacity: .2;
        filter:blur(5px);
        }
```

> So use before instead of hover.

Comment: Thank you, so much!

Comment: No problem. Can you accept the answer if it solved your problem ?